# Insertar fecha de manera correcta como Varchar en MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, mssql

¿Cómo va? Estoy intentando realizar un `UPDATE` a una tabla en `MSSQL`. Para ello, tengo un `WinForm` en `C#` con un botón que ejecuta el siguiente método:

```
    public void updateATemp(int dni, string descripcion, string usuario)
    {
        string queryUpdate = 
            "UPDATE Temp " +
            "SET Memo = Memo + " + 
                Environment.NewLine + " " +
                Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")) + " + '" + 
                descripcion + "' - '" +
                usuario + "' " +
            "WHERE DNI = @dni";
        using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(new Cadenas().DB_TEMP_DESARROLLO))
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(queryUpdate, sqlConnection);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dni", dni);
            try
            {
                sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            sqlConnection.Close();
        }
    }
```

El campo `Memo` contiene datos de tipo `varchar(max)`, a la hora de hacer el `UPDATE` necesito que se mantenga la información "**vieja"** y se añada la nueva con la fecha y hora actual más un mensaje predeterminado. Por ejemplo:

> Si el campo contenía: 09/12/2021 16:58 hola juan
>
> > Después del UPDATE debe quedar 09/12/2021 16:58 hola juan (salto de línea) 10/12/2021 15:58 hola pepito

Pero, me arroja error en la hora. Me dice:

```
Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de 15 (en este momento son las 15hs)
```

Ya probé:

```
                "SET Memo = Memo + " + 
                Environment.NewLine + " " +
                Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")) + " + '" + 

                "SET Memo = Memo + " + 
                Environment.NewLine + " + " +
                Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")) + " + '" + 

                "SET Memo = Memo CHAR(10) " +
                Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")) + " + '" + 

                "SET Memo = Memo CHAR(10) + " +
                Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")) + " + '" +
```

¿Cómo se almacena de manera correcta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución que hallé fue la siguiente, adjunto la respuesta por si a alguien le llega a ser útil:

```
    public void updateATemp(int dni, string descripcion, string usuario)
    {
        string fecha = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")) + "Hs. ";
        string queryUpdate =
            "UPDATE temp " +
            "SET Memo = Memo + CHAR(10) + @fecha + " +
                "@descripcion + " + " ' - ' + " + "@usuario " +
            "WHERE DNI = @dni";
        using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(new Cadenas().DB_TEMP_DESARROLLO))
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(queryUpdate, sqlConnection);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@dni", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = dni;
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@descripcion", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = descripcion;
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@fecha", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = fecha;
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@usuario", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = usuario;
            try
            {
                sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            sqlConnection.Close();
        }
    }
```